# Calling BLACS with more processes than used

Tags: fortran, openmpi, intel-mkl, scalapack

I want to create a parallel program, which makes heavy use of SCALAPACK. The basis of SCALAPACK is BLACS, which itself relies on MPI for interprocess communication.

I want to start the program with a defined number of processes (e.g. the number of cores on the machine) and let the algorithm decide, how to use these processes for calculations.

As a testcase I wanted to use 10 processes. 9 of these processes should get arranged in a grid (`BLACS_GRIDINIT`) and the 10th process should wait till the other processes are finished.

Unfortunately, OpenMPI crashes because the last process doesn't get into a MPI context from BLACS, while the others did.

**Question:** What is the correct way to use BLACS with more processes than needed?

I did some experiments with additional `MPI_INIT` and `MPI_FINALIZE` calls, but none of my tries were successful.

---

I started with the sample code from Intel MKL (shortened a little bit):

```
      PROGRAM HELLO 
*     -- BLACS example code --
*     Written by Clint Whaley 7/26/94 
*     Performs a simple check-in type hello world 
*     .. 
*     .. External Functions ..
      INTEGER BLACS_PNUM
      EXTERNAL BLACS_PNUM 
*     .. 
*     .. Variable Declaration ..
      INTEGER CONTXT, IAM, NPROCS, NPROW, NPCOL, MYPROW, MYPCOL
      INTEGER ICALLER, I, J, HISROW, HISCOL 

*     Determine my process number and the number of processes in 
*     machine 
      CALL BLACS_PINFO(IAM, NPROCS) 

*     Set up process grid that is as close to square as possible 
      NPROW = INT( SQRT( REAL(NPROCS) ) )
      NPCOL = NPROCS / NPROW 

*     Get default system context, and define grid
      CALL BLACS_GET(0, 0, CONTXT)
      CALL BLACS_GRIDINIT(CONTXT, 'Row', NPROW, NPCOL)
      CALL BLACS_GRIDINFO(CONTXT, NPROW, NPCOL, MYPROW, MYPCOL) 

*     If I'm not in grid, go to end of program 
      IF ( (MYPROW.GE.NPROW) .OR. (MYPCOL.GE.NPCOL) ) GOTO 30

*     Get my process ID from my grid coordinates 
      ICALLER = BLACS_PNUM(CONTXT, MYPROW, MYPCOL) 

*     If I am process {0,0}, receive check-in messages from 
*     all nodes 
      IF ( (MYPROW.EQ.0) .AND. (MYPCOL.EQ.0) ) THEN

         WRITE(*,*) ' '

         DO 20 I = 0, NPROW-1
            DO 10 J = 0, NPCOL-1

               IF ( (I.NE.0) .OR. (J.NE.0) ) THEN
                  CALL IGERV2D(CONTXT, 1, 1, ICALLER, 1, I, J)
               END IF 
*              Make sure ICALLER is where we think in process grid
              CALL BLACS_PCOORD(CONTXT, ICALLER, HISROW, HISCOL)
              IF ( (HISROW.NE.I) .OR. (HISCOL.NE.J) ) THEN
                 WRITE(*,*) 'Grid error!  Halting . . .'
                 STOP
              END IF
              WRITE(*, 3000) I, J, ICALLER
10         CONTINUE 
20      CONTINUE
        WRITE(*,*) ' '
        WRITE(*,*) 'All processes checked in.  Run finished.' 

*     All processes but {0,0} send process ID as a check-in
      ELSE
         CALL IGESD2D(CONTXT, 1, 1, ICALLER, 1, 0, 0)
      END IF

30    CONTINUE

      CALL BLACS_EXIT(0)

1000  FORMAT('How many processes in machine?') 
2000  FORMAT(I) 
3000  FORMAT('Process {',i2,',',i2,'} (node number =',I,
     $       ') has checked in.')

      STOP
      END
```

---

**Update:** I investigated the source code of `BLACS` to see, what happens there.

The call `BLACS_PINFO` initializes the MPI context with `MPI_INIT`, if this didn't happen before. This means, that at this point, everything works as expected.

At the end, the call to `BLACS_EXIT(0)` should free all resources from `BLACS` and if the argument is `0`, it should also call `MPI_FINALIZE`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected and my last process doesn't call `MPI_FINALIZE`.

As a workaround, one could ask `MPI_FINALIZED` and call `MPI_FINALIZE` if necessary.

**Update 2:** My previous tries were done with `Intel Studio 2013.0.079` and `OpenMPI 1.6.2` on `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11`.

After reading ctheo's answer, I tried to compile this example with the tools given by `Ubuntu 12.04` (`gfortran 4.6.3, OpenMPI 1.4.3, BLACS 1.1`) and was successful.

My conclusion is, that Intel's implementation appears to be buggy. I will retry this example in the not so far future with the newest service release of `Intel Studio`, but don't expect any changes.

*However, I would appreciate any other (and maybe better) solution.*

Comment: Are you using ScaLAPACK from MKL or another self-compiled implementation? It would be odd if you are the first one that needs to create grids with smaller number of processes than the total MPI job size.

Comment: @HristoIliev The problems appear while using ScaLAPACK from MKL. And I think, you misunderstood: I *wanted* to use less processes in the grid than the number of MPI processes available, because I wanted to use a square grid but start 10 MPI processes. Using 9 MPI processes causes no problems. In my second update, you can see that I have no problems when I use the precompiled version from Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my comment. Anyway, this is probably a bug in MKL, introduced in the 12.x compilers as it works properly with MKL from 11.1. The bug is still present in the latest and greatest beta compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, and I would hazard a guess that the set of people that participate in SO and those who know the answer to your question is < 1. However, I'd suggest that you might have slightly better luck asking on [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) or by contacting the ScaLAPACK team at the University of Tennessee directly through their [support page](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/index.html#_support). Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I think that the number of regular participants hereabouts who can answer this is approximately 2 (Jonathan Dursi and Hristo Iliev).  Let's wait and see.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I found an easy solution. I will try to redo this example with `GCC` and `BLACS` from netlib to see, whether this is a problem with `BLACS` itself or Intel's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to do much to use less processes in SCALAPACK.
The `BLACS_PINFO` subroutine returns the total number of processes.
If you want to use one less, just do `NPROCS = NPROCS - 1`.
I used your sample code (fixes some typos in FORMAT), added the subtraction and got the following output:

```
$ mpirun -n 4 ./a.out 

Process { 0, 0} (node number = 0) has checked in.
Process { 0, 1} (node number = 1) has checked in.
Process { 0, 2} (node number = 2) has checked in.

 All processes checked in.  Run finished.
```

The `BLACS_GRIDINIT` creates a grid with the reduced `NPROCS`.
By calling `BLACS_GRIDINFO` one process gets `MYPROW=MYPCOL=-1`

On the other hand if you want to create multiple grids that use different processes then probably you should use `BLACS_GRIDMAP` subroutine. The sample code below creates two equal grids with half size of total processes.

```
      PROGRAM HELLO 
*     .. 
      INTEGER CONTXT(2), IAM, NPROCS, NPROW, NPCOL, MYPROW, MYPCOL
      INTEGER ICALLER, I, J, HISROW, HISCOL
      integer UMAP(2,10,10)
*     
      CALL BLACS_PINFO(IAM, NPROCS) 
      NPROCS = NPROCS/2
*     
      NPROW = INT( SQRT( REAL(NPROCS) ) )
      NPCOL = NPROCS / NPROW 
*     
      DO IP = 1, 2
        DO I = 1, NPROW
          DO J = 1, NPCOL
            UMAP(IP,I,J) = (IP-1)*NPROCS+(I-1)*NPCOL+(J-1)
          ENDDO
        ENDDO
        CALL BLACS_GET(0, 0, CONTXT(IP))
        CALL BLACS_GRIDMAP(CONTXT(IP), UMAP(IP,:,:), 10, NPROW, NPCOL )
      ENDDO
*
      DO IP = 1, 2
        CALL BLACS_GRIDINFO(CONTXT(IP), NPROW, NPCOL, MYPROW, MYPCOL) 
        IF(MYPROW.GE.0 .AND. MYPCOL.GE.0 ) THEN
          WRITE(*,1000) IAM, MYPROW, MYPCOL, IP
        END IF
      ENDDO

      CALL BLACS_EXIT(0)
 1000 FORMAT('Process ',i2,' is (',i2,','i2 ') of grid ',i2)
*
      STOP
      END
```

I got the following output:

```
$ mpirun -n 8 ./a.out 
Process  0 is ( 0, 0) of grid  1
Process  1 is ( 0, 1) of grid  1
Process  2 is ( 1, 0) of grid  1
Process  3 is ( 1, 1) of grid  1
Process  4 is ( 0, 0) of grid  2
Process  5 is ( 0, 1) of grid  2
Process  6 is ( 1, 0) of grid  2
Process  7 is ( 1, 1) of grid  2
```

I did not collect the data in process zero. So you can get this output if all processes are local.

Comment: The reduction of `NPROCS` is implicitly done by using `NPROW` times `NPCOL` processes while setting up the grid. I already noticed, that the last process gets his copies of `(N|MY)PROW` and `(N|MY)PCOL` set to `-1` which is not clear from this source code. The main problem is simply that the process, which is not in the grid, doesn't call `MPI_FINALIZE` although this should be done in `BLACS_EXIT`. As a result, OpenMPI complains about abnormal termination, because the process called `MPI_INIT` without calling `MPI_FINALIZE`.

Comment: What compiler/OS/BLACS did you use?

Comment: I use gcc 4.7.3 on linux(ubuntu 13.04). Probably behavior depends on the os. To compile I used:
`mpif90 blacs.f -lscalapack-openmpi -lblacs-openmpi -lblacsF77init-openmpi`.
Also, I think that libblacsF77init takes care of the `MPI_INIT` and `MPI_FINALIZE` in fortran.